# Hang up with UART and DMA

Tags: stm32, usart

I am trying to use UART and DMA. When I insert a call to HAL_Delay() in the USART3_IRQHandler(), the program hang in the HAL_Delay(). The SysTick interrupt is not called anymore. I don't understand?

```
int main(void)
{
    ...
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  uint32_t nextCall = uwTick;
  while (1)
  {
     if (nextCall < uwTick) {
        __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart3, UART_IT_IDLE);
        HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA( &huart3, dataTx, sizeof( dataTx ) ); 
        nextCall = uwTick + 1000;
     }
  }
}

void USART3_IRQHandler(void)
{
    HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart3);
    if (( USART3->SR & UART_IT_IDLE) != 0 )
    {
        __HAL_UART_CLEAR_IDLEFLAG( &huart3 );
        HAL_UART_DMAStop(&huart3);
        uint8_t data_length  = sizeof( dataRx ) - __HAL_DMA_GET_COUNTER(&hdma_usart3_rx);
        memset( dataRx,0,sizeof( dataRx ));
        HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart3, (uint8_t*)dataRx, sizeof( dataRx ));
        HAL_Delay( 1 );
        //  Delay() does not return
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything is wrong there. You must choose Interrupt ot DMA. You cant start DMA receive in the UART interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

Abstracting from the completely wrong impossible to repair UART code HAL_Delay to work in the interrupt context requires SYSTICK interrupt priority to be higher than the UART interrupt. Otherwise it is not invoked and the internal counter does not increase and the function ends in the dead loop.

Comment: @P_J_ Thanks. Why can I start interrupt inside Interrupt. The idea is from [https://programming.vip/docs/stm32-hal-library-learning-serial-idle-interrupt.html]. 

The idea of a HAL_Delay() in the interrupt routine was only to be able to put a BReak in the code for debugging. Now, I know, it is a bad idea.

Comment: @YvonBlais your code does not have anything common with the linked one